# Oracle APEX copied, not migrated, to another CLOUD and I cannot log in

Tags: oracle-apex

DB = Oracle 12

APEX = 4.2

We are moving clouds and the PROD version of the DB with the APEX tables was copied and implemented into another cloud.

I have been told the clouds are exactly the same.

When I try and log into APEX via the web page e.g:

Workspace = Internal

User = ADMIN

I cannot get in.  I have tried my normal user and password and no success on any of the workspaces

At home I have installed APEX and have half an idea on what to do but I don’t have admin privileges on the DB.  So I have to pass on the messages to the DBA.

So far I have asked the DBA to unlock:

APEX_040200
APEX_PUBLIC_USER

On the connections, Im using SQL Developer to migrate around the DB, the Hostname and Servicename have changed.

Would the change in Service and Host cause logging in issues.

Or, am I missing something obvious, is it a complete re-install, is there a procedure that can be run to update things??

Any tips appreciated

Cheers

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my defence I am not a DBA.

When I was told the DB was getting copied I assumed I did not need to do anything since all the data should be held in the tables and it would be a simple case of logging in as usual.

Life is never that simple.

So, when I tried to log in I kept getting errors i.e. invalid log in credentials.

Resolution:

1   DBA resets the ADMIN password and supplies me with the details

2   Go to Production and export all the workspaces etc

3   As ADMIN recreate myself in the INTERNAL workspace

4   Log into INTERNAL, as myself not ADMIN, and import the workspaces